# Showing/hiding label by another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Someting doesn't work in my code so I wanted to ask if someone can help me. I have this so far:

```
private void searchList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(setLabel));
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();

            //some code that needs time
  if (searchBox.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            listViewType.Items.Clear();
            fillListView();
        }

        else
        {

            listViewType.Items.Clear();
            var matchings = stringTypes.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return s.StartsWith(searchBox.Text); });

            for (int i = 0; i < matchings.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem storeMatched = new ListViewItem(matchings[i]);
                storeMatched.SubItems.Add(matchings[i]);
                listViewType.Items.Add(storeMatched);

            }

            th.Abort();
            searchLabel.Visible = false;
}

     private void setLabel()
    {
        MethodInvoker set = () => searchLabel.Visible = true;
        searchLabel.BeginInvoke(set);
    }
```

So searchLabel is a label that I want to show/hide. I tried here to show the label before the operation begins and hide it after it finished. Somehow it gets shown AFTER the code was executed (//some code that needs time) and then stays visible. How to code that correctly?

Comment: The whole process is not clear for me. It seems more logical to put "code that need time" to background thread. In UI thread (or main thread) you should easily change Visible status of label. After that just invoke Visible status to True in background thread after it finishes.

Comment: I wanted to do it that way. Is it possible? I tried "Invoke" now but it's still the same

Answer (score 2):

```
private void searchList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchLabel.Visible = false;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //some code that needs time
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    SetLabelVisible(true);
}

private delegate void SetLabelVisibleDelegate(bool status);

private void SetLabelVisible(bool status)
{
    if (searchLabel.InvokeRequired)
        searchLabel.Invoke(new SetLabelVisibleDelegate(SetLabelVisible), status);
    else
        searchLabel.Visible = status;
}
```

Comment: Somehow he does not want to start the "doWork" method. It never gets reached.

Comment: @ScorpX you should add BackgroundWorker control through VS Designer and then auto-generate two event handlers subroutine: DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: Yes that was the case. Thank you very much! :) I will still try the other answer.

Comment: Ok. He still does not want to start the doWork method. I have made a new worker and linked everything to the methods.

Comment: @ScorpX thats probably because newly added worker used to be named "backgroundWorker1" and my one above is "backgroundWorker" :)

Comment: Ok solved it - You were right. But like the other solution, I had to do invokes on some methods which call my ListView. It's very slow now. I can see the ListView loading. That takes about 5 times longer than usual.

Comment: @ScorpX if you provide us rest of the code, we could guess why its 5 times slower (thats really weird and shouldnt be the case)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing work on the UI thread

Your

```
//some code that needs time
```

Will hang the UI thread so will not re-draw, you should use the new async / await stuff

Task.Run might not be right for your case but I would need to understand the 'some code' more.

```
private async void searchList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchLabel.Visible = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // code that needs time 
    });

    // simulate
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    searchLabel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: The "some code" just searches in a ListView. So it takes the Textbox input, clears the listview, searches the substring in a list, puts the strings which match into a new list and then fills the ListView with these strings and shows them.

Comment: this should be fine, make sure you don't manipulate your list view on the non UI thread. Try the code above with the Delay and you will see that it works.

Comment: He takes very long to load... much longer than usual.