# "Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" after closing form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I have a problem and don't know how to solve it. I've got a Form2 which I open from my Form1 by a button click.
In this form2 I do some operations on a ListView. While the operations are working in the background I want to show another form (Form3) which gets opened in that time. So I did the following:

```
public void method()
 {
  Form3 form3 = Form3.GetInstance();

        if (thrd == null)
        {
            thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showForm));
            thrd.IsBackground = true;
            thrd.Start();
        }

        else
        {
            if (form3.InvokeRequired)
            {
                form3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    form3.Show();
                }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                form3.Show();
            }
        }

     //some operations getting invoked

        if (form3.InvokeRequired)
            {
                form3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    form3.Hide();
                }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                form3.Hide();
            }
}


   private void showForm()
    {
        Form3 form3 = Form3.GetInstance();
        Application.Run(Form3.GetInstance());
    }
```

And the code from the Form3:

```
    private static Form3 m_instance = null;
    private static object m_instanceLock = new object();

    public static Form3 GetInstance()
    {

        lock (m_instanceLock)
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new Form3();
            }
        }

        return m_instance;
    }
```

So when I open the Form2 and do my stuff there everything works fine. When I call operations that need longer then the Form3 shows up and closes when operations are done. But when I close my Form2 and then open it again (without closing Form1) then I get the Exception mentioned above in the headline at the Application.Run method. Why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve actually? If you want to show another form, just call `Form.Show`. Don't mess up with worker threads and windows. Winform controls have thread affinity.

Comment: I have to do it this way because else the form2 freezes and shows nothing. I need a separate thread for this. It's just a "Please wait" form I show while form2 freezes while computing.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. As far as the threading goes, it doesn't matter why you _think_ you have to do it that way, don't do it that way. It is always possible to implement the code so that all UI happens in a single thread, and no part of the UI is "frozen". Ask for help with _that_, not for help with getting the incorrect implementation to work.

Comment: It is very important that you don't do this, displaying UI on a worker thread causes [very nasty bugs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx) if it is not done excessively carefully.  You've only seen the tip of that iceberg.  Run expensive code on a worker thread, never the UI thread.  Use BackgroundWorker for example.

Comment: Oh ok. I've already tried that with a backgroundworker and also with an async method. That works but the computing takes much longer than when I go the normal way without. That was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253301/showing-hiding-label-by-another-thread/29253734?noredirect=1#comment46713203_29253734

Answer (score 0):

Ok this may not be the best way but I solved the problem now. I just had to put the code where he creates the Thread, shows the form and hides the form into my Form1. This prevents him crashing when the form gets opened a second time.